# Add a clear/reset input to a when select statement in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I am hoping to get some help on how to add a clear or reset input to this code so at any time when the clr input is a `1` then the_output_S resets to `0000`. This code works great to run through the truth table I need it to but I can't seem to figure out any kind of clear input that works properly. I tried to add a with clr_S select `the_output_S <= "0000"` when `1`, `the_output_S` when `0`, `XXXX` when others; I'm just not sure how to point to my truth table when clr is '0'. Any suggestions on how to add this would be appreciated. Thank you

```
library IEEE;

    use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
    use IEEE.std_logic_arith.all;
    use IEEE.std_logic_unsigned.all;

Entity Design_Proj_8K is
port(
    --clr : in std_logic;

    INA : in std_logic;
    INB : in std_logic;
    INC : in std_logic;
    IND : in std_logic;
    INE : in std_logic);

end Design_Proj_8K;

 architecture Behaviroal of Design_Proj_8K is

 signal the_input_S: std_logic_vector (4 downto 0);
 signal the_output_S: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
 --signal clr_S: std_logic;

begin

--clr_S <= clr;

the_input_S <= INA & INB & INC & IND & INE;

with the_input_S select
                    the_output_S <= 
                    "0000" when "00000",
                    "0000" when "00001",
                    "0000" when "00010",
                    "0001" when "00011",
                    "0001" when "00100",
                    "0001" when "00101",
                    "0010" when "00110",
                    "0010" when "00111",
                    "0010" when "01000",
                    "0011" when "01001",
                    "0011" when "01010",
                    "0011" when "01011",
                    "0100" when "01100",
                    "0100" when "01101",
                    "0100" when "01110",
                    "0101" when "01111",
                    "0101" when "10000",
                    "0101" when "10001",
                    "0110" when "10010",
                    "0110" when "10011",
                    "0110" when "10100",
                    "0111" when "10101",
                    "0111" when "10110",
                    "0111" when "10111",
                    "1000" when "11000",
                    "1000" when "11001",
                    "1000" when "11010",
                    "1001" when "11011",
                    "XXXX" when others;


end Behaviroal;
```

Comment: Stopped counting after finding 12 different ways. Here's a low effort way `subtype input_subtype is std_logic_vector (the_input_S'range);` as an architectural declarative item, and `the_input_s <= ina & inb & inc & ind & ine and input_subtype'(others => clr);`. Any particular reason why you're using a *selected signal assignment statement*? The adding operator & (concatenation) is higher priority than the logical operator and.

Comment: In -2008 that could be `the_input_S <= ina & inb & inc & ind & ine and clr;` without the subtype declaration. Where the_input_S is all zeros when each element of the cocatenation is anded with clr and clr = '0' for `function "and"  (l : STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR; r : STD_ULOGIC) return STD_ULOGIC_VECTOR;` (package std_logic_1164). That matches up with the first choice in the existing selected signal assignment statement.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to make the result in an internal value, and then use `clr` to override this before outputting the final value, like:

```
...
signal the_output_S_pre : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
signal the_output_S     : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
...

with the_input_S select
  the_output_S_pre <=
  ...

the_output_S <= the_output_S_pre when (clr = '0') else "0000";

...
```